# How to detect an asp.net core api user is human?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, captcha

I have a web site created using Asp.net core mvc and it also has a web api that implements all crud operations in web application. for web application I used captcha anywhere that an anonymous user enters data. is there any way like captcha to secure the web api and prevent bots to enter data via api?

Comment: Generally , you need to make an Api Gateway. 
that handel those sorts of stuff. 
your api Job to handel the Core/Business needs.

you can also use close circle which blocks the spamming

Comment: Can you provide an example please? I want calling my api methods without providing valid captcha code be imposible!

Answer (score 0):

Finally after a lot of search, I decided to do below scenario although I have not any idea if this is the best practice!

1- in the view that consumes the api, I have an img tag with src from api get method that takes the captcha image and in same time saves captcha code in httpcontext.session.

2- by sending data containing captcha code using ajax post to server, I will compare sent captcha code with one that was saved before in httpcontext.session.